# Token handler unable to convert the token to jwt token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, jwt

I'm trying to convert my token string to jwt token using `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`. But it's getting error that saying

> IDX12709: CanReadToken() returned false. JWT is not well formed: '[PII is hidden]'.\nThe token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. (JWS): 'EncodedHeader.EndcodedPayload.EncodedSignature'. (JWE): 'EncodedProtectedHeader.EncodedEncryptedKey.EncodedInitializationVector.EncodedCiphertext.EncodedAuthenticationTag'.

How can I solve this issue?

Here is my token

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwibmJmIjoxNTUwNjM3NzcxLCJleHAiOjE1NTA2Mzg5NzEsImlhdCI6MTU1MDYzNzc3MX0.tUcoyoHgkrX3rDKl0cRLd9FwLtRprQpgYepMoiekixY

```
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwtToken = tokenHandler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
```

Calling web api

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string path = "UserMaintenance/ValidateUserId?userid=" + txtUsername.Text.Trim().ToString();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(GlobalData.BaseUri);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer" + GlobalData.Token);
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(path).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var value = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    isValid = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(value);
                }
            }
```

Here is my GetPrincipal method

```
public static ClaimsPrincipal GetPrincipal(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            var symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Secret);
            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey)
            };

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            handler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            SecurityToken securityToken;
            var principal = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken);

            return principal;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add the token to your question?

Comment: Here is my token : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwibmJmIjoxNTUwNjM3NzcxLCJleHAiOjE1NTA2Mzg5NzEsImlhdCI6MTU1MDYzNzc3MX0.tUcoyoHgkrX3rDKl0cRLd9FwLtRprQpgYepMoiekixY"

Comment: Both your code and my code are working with this token. On which line exactly is the exception thrown?

Comment: from the line "tokenHandler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken"

Comment: Have you traced the code and checked if jwt has the required value at the mentioned line? And have removed the **"Bearer "** word from the beginning of the token?

Comment: I haven't remove the "Bearer".From where should I remove it?

Comment: I updated my answer. After you read the Authorization value from the header you need to remove the bearer from the beginning of the string and then try to parse it to jwt token.

Comment: Just in case you didn't notice, there is also a space after Bearer that must be removed too. So it's **bearer plus space** (i.e. **"Bearer "**)

Comment: still not work for me.when I remove the space between Bearer and token I'm getting a exception saying "The format of value 'Bearer"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwibmJmIjoxNTUwNjQ0ODQ0LCJleHAiOjE1NTA2NDYwNDQsImlhdCI6MTU1MDY0NDg0NH0.rgxW577uqxETbLMMwZZOE_vGdkTitDuA6uhooL1rQrU"' is invalid."

Comment: I edited my code here,Attached my web api calling part.

Comment: When initializing the authorization header, you are missing the space after Bearer. Let me clarify more: Imagine XXX is your token. In the first step, when you want to call an api you need to add this string to authorization header: **"Bearer XXX"**. And in the second step, when you want to consume and parse the token you need remove the **"Bearer "** from the beginning of the authorization header and parse exactly the value of XXX without any prefix.

Comment: As for your comment I tried "var jwtToken = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken(token)". now i'm getting the jwt token.but still have an issue generating the principal.

Comment: I think this could be a different question and needs more details.

Comment: Updated my source code.Please refer.

Comment: Since each post might be searched and used by other users in future, I suggest that you keep the original question untouched and create a new post for the Principle issue.

Comment: Create a new question for Principle issue.Can you address the issue?

Comment: Ok, I'm going to search it.   
Regarding this post, if my answer was the right answer to your question please mark it as answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188751/discussion-between-thilim9-and-rad).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is how I do it and it works for me:

```
var token = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken(jwt);
```

> The above line works for `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` package version `4.0.0`.
>   As @Nick commented, in the latest versions of the package, the `JwtSecurityToken` does not exist in the previous namespace anymore, instead it exists in `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` so you need to write:
>       `var token = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken(jwt);`

Unless your token is not well-formed. It would be better if you share the token too.

## Update:

You also need to remove the word **"Bearer "** from the beginning of the token (If you haven't):

```
 var jwt = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].Replace("Bearer ", string.Empty);
```

Comment: The type or namespace name 'JwtSecurityToken' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens'

Comment: @Nick I double-checked and yes it's about the version. In `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` `version=4.0.0` the `JwtSecurityToken` class was inside `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` but in the latest versions it was removed from the namespace and placed inside `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`. Weak documentation of Microsoft.

Comment: It was not removed in the latest version. I've looked back 10 versions, all releases through 2016, and it's still in `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`. Why answer the question based on a random version of a package that was released in 2014, when there were already 17 newer versions at the time the answer was posted?

Comment: Thanks for the hint of removing the 'Bearer ' part. Still, I had to add a .ToString() call to to make it work for me: var jwt = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", string.Empty);

Comment: I have to remove the Bearer and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might be a late post but I recently upgraded my project from dotnet 7 to dotnet version 8.

I started receiving the following error, when I looked into the JwtHandler code:

```
Information: Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX14100: JWT is not well formed, there are no dots (.).
The token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. (JWS): 'EncodedHeader.EndcodedPayload.EncodedSignature'. (JWE): 'EncodedProtectedHeader.EncodedEncryptedKey.EncodedInitializationVector.EncodedCiphertext.EncodedAuthenticationTag'.
```

So I had my token being generated using the following:

```
return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(...);
```

After I've changed it to the following implementation it started working again:

```
return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().CreateEncodedJwt(...);
```

I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, but it seems it could be padding on the encoded bytes which changed on dotnet version 8.

Hopefully this helps someone - FYI, it's not easy finding detailed errors within the `jwtbearer lib => jwthandler` even when enabling `LogValidationExceptions` on the `options config`.

I had to add my own `custom` version of `jwthandler scheme`, which essentially just mimics what the existing `jwtbearer lib` does, here is an example:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddScheme<JwtBearerOptions, JwtCustomHandler>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
    options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            LogValidationExceptions = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"] ?? ""))
        };
    });
```

Comment: DUDE! THANK YOU! I just updated NuGet packages, including JWT tokens related, and suddenly started receiving "bearer error = invalid_token" . I managed to find same error message as you have and I got it fixed by your example.

Answer (score 0):

at version 5.6.0.0 - currently is the latest version
can use similar code as in @thilim9's question.

```
var tokenId = identity.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "id_token")?.Value;
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
JwtSecurityToken token = handler.ReadJwtToken(tokenId);
```

Answer (score 0):

For .net framework 4.5.1 I remove my custom key while generating token and use default values in claims of `JwtRegisteredClaimNames`.

```
var claims = new[] 
{
     new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName, Data.UserName),
     new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Prn,Data.Password),
     new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue quickly by adding the field below:

UseSecurityTokenValidators = true;

Details are here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/8.0/securitytoken-events

Example:   .AddJwtBearer(x=>
{x.UseSecurityTokenValidators=true;}