# Why Authorize attribute not working with this Configuration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity

Thats how my Jwt configuration looks like:

```
 services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

 services
 .AddAuthentication(options =>
 {
     options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 })
 .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
 {
     cfg.SaveToken = true;
     cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
     cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
     {
         ValidateIssuer = true,
         ValidateAudience = true,
         ValidAudience = jwtSettings.Audience,
         ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.Issuer,
         IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Secret))
     };
 });
```

and thats JwtBearerSettings

```
  "JwtBearerSettings": {
    "Issuer": "https://localhost:7032/",
    "Audience": "https://localhost:7032/",
    "Secret": "JWTAuthenticationHIGHsecuredPasswordVVVp1OH7Xzyr"
  }
```

Thats How I sign in User

```
        public override async Task<CommandResult> Handle(SignInCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(command.Email);
            if (user == null)
                return await FailAsync(ErrorCode.NotFound);

            var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName,
                                                                        user.Password,
                                                                        command.RememberMe,
                                                                        false);

            if (!signInResult.Succeeded)
                return await FailAsync();

            var accessToken = GenerateAccessToken(user);

            return await OkAsync(accessToken);
        }

        private string GenerateAccessToken(User user)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_jwtBearerSettings.Secret));

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _jwtBearerSettings.Issuer,
                audience: _jwtBearerSettings.Audience,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
                claims: claims,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                );

            var accessToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

            return accessToken;
        }
```

But Authorize attribute still does not work. It gives me 401 error

I have tried adding ValidateIssuer and ValidateAudience to be false but still not working.
The Jwt Configuration part is inside DependencyResolver class which is called from Program.cs
and after this in Program.cs I am using services.Authenticate and services.Authorize methods

Comment: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenMalformedException: IDX14100: JWT is not well formed, there are no dots (.).
The token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. (JWS): 'EncodedHeader.EndcodedPayload.EncodedSignature'. (JWE): 'EncodedProtectedHeader.EncodedEncryptedKey.EncodedInitializationVector.EncodedCiphertext.EncodedAuthenticationTag'.

Comment: my idea is that we need to make sure the variable is correct, you might change to hard code the value just like what I showed below. Then let's check if there's anything wrong when calling the API.

Answer (score 0):

Pls allow me to show my codes with variables here so that we can see it in a good format.

I tried your code in my side which worked well when generating token and use token to call the API. The only difference is the parameter value as some of yours are using variable, so that checking the variables first. Here's my test result.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
 .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
 {
     cfg.SaveToken = true;
     cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
     cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
     {
         ValidateIssuer = false,
         ValidateAudience = false,
         ValidAudience = "Test.com",
         ValidIssuer = "Test.com",
         IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is my custom Secret key for authentication"))
     };
 });

private string GenerateAccessToken()
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name, "username1"),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    };

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is my custom Secret key for authentication"));

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: "Test.com",
        audience: "Test.com",
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
        claims: claims,
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        );

    var accessToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

    return accessToken;
}
```

By the way, you also shared an exception which looks like related to token deserialization, could you pls share how you decode your code? I searched the exception message and [here's a ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54778989) with many votes, could you pls confirm whether you added Request Header with `Authorization: Bearer {token}`?