# Access Token not working of tenant of office 365

Tags: azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, access-token

I am working in add-in that's why i am using office dialog to login

```
var url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=myclientid&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/assets/Redirect.html&scope=user.read%20mail.readwrite%20mail.send&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910";
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, {  height: 60, width: 40 }, function (asyncResult) {
Logindialog = asyncResult.value;
Logindialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, function (arg) {
  token = arg.message;
  });
});
```

I am getting token After successfully login using this in my `redirect.html` file

```
 var address_Link = window.location.href;
 console.log(address_Link)
 var address_arr = address_Link.split("=");
 var address_Token = address_arr[1];
 var Id_Token = address_Token.split("&");
 var access_token = Id_Token[0];
 console.log(Id_Token);
 Office.onReady(function (appInfo) {    
  Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify(access_token));
 })
```

**my simple Microsoft Account token looks like this**

EwCoA8l6BAAUs5%2bHQn0N%2bh2FxWzLS31ZgQVuHsYAASzDAo%2bzOHW8bimiwipl3VtTsk4JI1MUN2Osop4ryl1wGSRhZypgzfO/ff1zkOGAzStT4BsAzkSOV/0LiCtQ2MTB2RsR1%2buhflh3Pq2CwOawwTS7nj/%2bKnDFvH3N9h6N8uwruiEH4OZekE0gfk4fOfY2Go5IgrWUfbs%2bjcbNXKGv/Ekc4PeSXNaII5mCyBjLVuvxvLHhrZzAL7tu8AxCFyd5XxAWP6pXjJRZk7ow0ChUQeNNPNP5/rWSTLBbMu3AORmKIi%2bvfdvVcxhmmQmpAgU4glN6BIR7gKj6pkvhKQVydGIvTPvFlLOvWJItF5um8ignPEgP43gMqmPsH07xFJcDZgAACBbA8fXreaJdeAK%2bseTrYHH7KxKhAhPIN2sZUfAZKPHjuoPqhQopFvQFxWUljFOlJzHWn00pHbW3pVm95S58HngtIYDzNg9uKqIm9O3VJdrwctgnsDA5cMNPFzyOb3nYh58BSdefe3c42D1n7ovKtUjKtQR%2b5zJrocarrhwXhYLvXbAg2kMliEc1zqiCbyH6ila5s63mWaoufy%2bFnPkW9nyQ2qaTfqWgFa0tHlaNgWf9a2j5zlLUFTvaw9zLRtilFLWoOv1FMfEzw/A7WaebYW4DHCOeMJIkd2NjHGtqg3kXj0cXf1Jt2xQnoIG8vR5w%2bzqI/tfqMAMkJSOSGCLRdjNjUadF8NNYFbzoLX8TPeYarwHWJRbXBUtbBhOpRJE/DTwaJh800AcUBM6y5v1bFnRBWtdAYtrlefL0lQT2FodrcpcVH9AAao2ks2EQa0Xla8D39dYDcGqQ1mg3VCzjz7qNlhnIP6D30oL%2bzM8oTjjZahKE62ISPcpWEVTPQ3s7CddKYR6TJ86xmLGqTedK1u5xypHopSXTRzCbLvu6pGaKZy%2bacDVwT8YzABbZfGYdZnmh6CDfoYubYI924O0r22XC1rtrdGv9ghCDkZEcGIIiJelTiTRpgP/QDHlXW2Qci4gwRUK3cIYCTQds9Z2PA6sn3iDpa/Sf8vyaQZ1m99Rek8mVifBkGxOr2O7t5Tzq69sBOMylz7y7SvWlHEgqpC%2bSQ3/eQX6wcOEbrdldqFA5yu%2bqm0bANF5RIc1L7AZo/PagLt1DmAILJKIxomQ5pTelqeXpAKUM4qN%2b4ym4TKhINqNAnks4rd4/1aLeVG9o%2bZG98f6ePdGKf4MC9%2boSKewl2qgC

**when I login with tenant of office 365 I got token like this**

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkJneVFGOVVSTm5RSlh4end2MTlsTGV6QWFqUG9maFBJUEdSUmtXOTVTSnMiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImtXYmthYTZxczh3c1RuQndpaU5ZT2hIYm5BdyIsImtpZCI6ImtXYmthYTZxczh3c1RuQndpaU5ZT2hIYm5BdyJ9.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.LS0n3DWrv-YHufr9oA4PW97_nwQ_oP6Z4e-jdWvQrU97nznZQs9w-qfeRvtijUXvmVEGo8fyUgCCZ1UNLB3pbOIWZYIOPhXmsGiWs5sjdn9-vKT-394jBUqCqkaLXa2aldBWGUmklDJ81TYzFV4C7BEjQang162KjHqetXg118OEmDZaayd1VyNWIc2xQ6RK-gmxvPOqv8CPIAOj4fQ8HcQxpUtpSONr98mVwX4potYpJVV2Vn6-gaLF86DYNrxw1rBt3qOMhCInHMwxgQHsLK_XO2tnSoJ-LZzk5NusOOpnM4GVrcsKgA9jUK3NwBrJYpda2RAkcHfcM5hkOYxc1A

- **with my first token of simple Microsoft account is working correctly when I send a mail but my second office 365 Account token gives `error status of 401`
  what is the difference between these tokens how can I send mail using both tokens?**

Comment: If what you get back is a "code" query parameter, then it is not a token, but an authorization code. That needs to be exchanged for tokens.

Comment: @juunas how bro I haave not experience in this what should I need to do?

Comment: I am working in a add-in and trying to login a office dialog with login url it looks like this

' var a = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=myclientid&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/assets/Redirect.html&scope=user.read%20mail.readwrite%20mail.send&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910";
 '

Comment: Can you check whether the Azure ad account has active O365 license or not

Comment: @Rukmini thanks for replying 
I have license I have created user in Azure when U login with that user its give some different type of token and this token is not working when I am trying to send email giving `error 401 unauthorized`.
I am developing a add-in so I am calling login with `https://localhost:3000`

Comment: xx@fundatio.org is  a custom domain user? and do you have any user like xxx@onmicrosoft.com domain?

Comment: when I have login user like this example xx@fundatio.org then token gives error 401

Comment: Yes, is fundatio.org a custom domain you configured?

Comment: @Rukmini
xx@fundatio.org is a custom domain user? what it's mean I don't know con you please make a good answer that I understand what I need to do

Comment: @Rukmini
I didn't any answer related my issue my issue is Access Token of  Azure user not working on send email.

Comment: AFAIK I know the user is a custom domain user not Microsoft domain that is xxx@onmicrosoft.com user and so the issue is occuring

Comment: @Rukmini
now I got your point, thanks you very much.
is there any way to fix this problem

Comment: @Rukmini
you can make a simple answer i will accept it, thanks

Comment: Did your issue resolve by making use of  xxx@onmicrosoft.com user?

Comment: not may me this is not possible with user like  xx@fundatio.org

Comment: Okay I will post it as an answer

Comment: @Rukmini
did you mean this will work with user like this xxx@onmicrosoft.com ?

Comment: Yes it will work with user xxx@onmicrosoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a workaround, make use of Microsoft domain user like **`xxx@onmicrosoft.com`.**

Created a Microsoft Entra ID application and granted API permissions:

[image]

Now I generated  **auth-code**  using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

Generated  **access token**  via Postman by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID  
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:authorization_code  
code:code  
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:Secret
```

[image]

Decoded the access token:

[image]

Now by using the above access token,  **I am able to send mail successfully:**

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail
Content-type: application/json

{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "ccRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[user: sendMail - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: I tried but still not working can you please try this that way I have shared in my question with office dialog. can I give you a account to test like democlients.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: Even with onmicrosoft.com its not working?

Comment: I tried this is working on postman but not working in my code

Comment: there is a problem in  generating access token in code

Comment: same token I used that token I am getting from my code this token is working on postman

Comment: How are you passing the token in the code to send mail?

Comment: I am getting this error  [image](https://imgur.com/download/9we8DaX/)

Comment: Can you paste it in the form of text unable to open the link

Comment: message
: 
"IDX14100: JWT is not well formed, there are no dots (.).\nThe token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. (JWS):

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778724/token-handler-unable-to-convert-the-token-to-jwt-token

Comment: same token is working on postman

Comment: I am using only javascript

Comment: You can use this script to send mail https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#request

Comment: I have fixed this issue When i office 365 tenant Account Access Token this have dots and this is long then simple account token when I use this token this is used as a string just I remove its double quotes like this 
`const tokenWithoutQuotes = token.replace(/"/g, '');`